# sed/awk between two patterns in a file: pattern 1 set by a variable from lines of a second file; pattern 2 designated by a specified charcacter

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have two files. One file contains a pattern that I want to match in a second file. I want to use that pattern to print between that pattern (included) up to a specified character (not included) and then concatenate into a single output file.

For instance,

File_1:

```
a
c
d
```

and File_2:

```
>a
MEEL
>b
MLPK
>c
MEHL
>d
MLWL
>e
MTNH
```

I have been using variations of this loop:

```
while read $id;
     do 
       sed -n "/>$id/,/>/{//!p;}" File_2;
done < File_1
```

hoping to obtain something like the following output:

```
>a
MEEL
>c
MEHL
>d
MLWL
```

But have had no such luck. I have played around with grep/fgrep awk and sed and between the three cannot seem to get the right (or any output). Would someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: You seem to be processing FASTA file, is that right? If so, please add the [tag:fasta] tag.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$ awk -F'>' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next}  NF==2{f=$2 in a} f'  file1 file2
>a
MEEL
>c
MEHL
>d
MLWL
```

#### How it works

- `-F'>'`

  This sets the field separator to `>`.
- `FNR==NR{a[$1]; next}`

  While reading in the first file, this creates a key in array `a` for every line in file `file`.
- `NF==2{f=$2 in a}`

  For every line in file 2 that has two fields, this sets variable `f` to true if the second field is a key in `a` or false if it is not.
- `f`

  If `f` is true, print the line.

Comment: This assumes that every `>` indicates the start of a header and never occurs line-internally. If the main file is in fact a FASTA file, I believe this is a valid assumption. With GNU Awk you could set the record separator to a regex pattern like `^>`.

Comment: `f` is a toggle that will still be true on following data lines of matched keys, and still be false on following data lines of unmatches keys - yes? I'd just like to say, this is beautiful, if obtuse. XD

Answer (score 2):

A plain (GNU) `sed` solution. Files are read only once. It is assumed that  characters in File_1 needn't to be quoted in sed expression.

```
pat=$(sed ':a; $!{N;ba;}; y/\n/|/' File_1)
sed -E -n ":a; /^>($pat)/{:b; p; n; /^>/ba; bb}" File_2
```

**Explanation:**
The first call to `sed` generates a regular expression to be used in the second call to `sed` and stores it in the variable `pat`. The aim is to avoid reading repeatedly the entire File_2 for each line of File_1. It just "slurps" the File_1 and replaces new-line characters with `|` characters. So the sample File_1 becomes a string with the value `a|c|d`. The regular expression `a|c|d` matches if at least one of the alternatives (`a`, `b`, `c` for this example) matches (this is a GNU sed extension).

The second `sed` expression, `":a; /^>($pat)/{:b; p; n; /^>/ba; bb}"`, could be converted to pseudo code like this:

```
begin:
    read next line (from File_2) or quit on end-of-file
label_a:
    if line begins with `>` followed by one of the alternatives in `pat` then
label_b:
        print the line
        read next line (from File_2) or quit on end-of-file
        if line begins with `>` goto label_a else goto label_b
    else goto begin
```

Comment: This is the solution I would have suggested (though I actually like the Awk one better) but you should probably explain in more detail how you are using `sed` to generate a script for ... `sed`. The `ed` solution is vaguely similar, but arguably more esoteric. The main point is that given a good script, `sed` only needs to process the main input file once. This avoids the pesky ` while read` loop which neds up reading the input file from start to finish as many times as you have input patterns.

Comment: Storing the pattern in a variable you only use once is vaguely problematic, especially if you have a lot of patterns.

Comment: @tripleee I agree that the awk solution is better (and elegant). I will add an explanation to my answer. The command substitution (in the first line) could be embedded into the `sed` expression (in the second line) but then it would be harder to follow that long line.

Comment: On some platforms you can do `sed something | sed -f -` to pass the generated script to the second `sed` instance on standard input. That will require some refactoring in this case, and some `sed` implementations simply won't accept a script on stdin.

Comment: @tripleee In `bash`, process substitution could be used as well. For example, this works for `bash` and GNU `sed`: `sed -E -n -f <(echo -n ':a; /^>('; sed ':a; $!{N;ba;}; y/\n/|/' File_1 | tr -d '\n'; echo ')/{:b; p; n; /^>/ba; bb}') File_2`, but is hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain why your approach does not work well:

- You need to say `while read id` instead of `while read $id`.
- The `sed` command `/>$id/,/>/{//!p;}` will exclude the lines which start
  with `>`.

Then you might want to say something like:

```
while read id; do
    sed -n "/^>$id/{N;p}" File_2
done < File_1
```

Output:

```
>a
MEEL
>c
MEHL
>d
MLWL
```

But the code above is inefficient because it reads `File_2` as many times as the count of the id's in `File_1`.
Please try the elegant solution by John1024 instead.

Comment: Running `sed` inside a `while read` loop is basically always wrong.

Comment: @tripleee true. I just guessed what the OP wanted to say. I do not intend to use sed inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available, and since the shell is involve.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mapfile -t to_match < file1.txt

ed -s file2.txt <<-EOF                                               
  g/\(^>[${to_match[*]}]\)/;/^>/-1p
  q
EOF
```

- It will only run `ed` once and not every line that has the pattern, that matches from file1. Like say if you have `a` to `z` from file1,`ed` will not run 26 times.
- Requires bash4+ because of mapfile.

---

How it works

- `mapfile -t to_match < file1.txt`
  Saves the entry/value from file1 in an array named `to_match`
- `ed -s file2.txt` point ed to file2 with the `-s` flag which means don't print info about the file, same info you get with `wc file`
- `<<-EOF` A here document, shell syntax.

```
g/\(^>[${to_match[*]}]\)/;/^>/-1p
```

- `g` means search the whole file aka global.
- `( )` capture group, it needs escaping because `ed` only supports BRE, basic regular expression.
- `^>` If line starts with a `>` the `^` is an anchor which means the start.
- `[  ]` is a bracket expression match whatever is inside of it, in this case the value of the array `"${to_match[*]}"`
- `;` Include the next address/pattern
- `/^>/` Match a leading `>`
- `-1` go back one line after the pattern match.
- `p` print whatever was matched by the pattern.
- `q` quit `ed`